# Django template substitution in include JS scripts

Tags: django, templates

I've got a javascript widget written for my Django project, which is included at the top of my templates.

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/widget.js"></script>
```

The widget needs to load its own stylesheet, but since it's not actually a Django template, it doesn't know where the static root is. Does it need find its .css relative to itself, or is there a way for Django to tell it about `{{ STATIC_URL }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do relative URLs in your Javascript, which is probably preferable, or you can define a global variable:

```
<script>var static_url = '{{ STATIC_URL }}';</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/widget.js"></script>
```

Then, you can use `static_url` anywhere in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the STATIC_URL variable in your settings.py file, making it accessible on your entire site.

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://your.js.server'
```

Comment: This variable won't be accessible from any of my javascript libraries.